# concept drift detection

Tags: time-series, concept-drift

I'm working on a project that involves [concept drift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_drift) detection for a time series. Are there any well-known techniques/methods/algorithms that are known to be effective for this sort of problem?

Currently, I was thinking of using a Kalman filter approach.

Answer (score 1):

You might find these useful:

- Learn++.NSE from Prof.Robi Polikar. [This](http://users.rowan.edu/~polikar/RESEARCH/index_files/Ensemble.html) is his official page which offers lots of additional information, papers on the topic etc. and it is a great starting point.
- The GitHub repository of [gditzler](https://github.com/gditzler/IncrementalLearning) contains an implementation of incremental learners in MATLAB.

Additionally the Concept Drift wiki page, under sections *Projects* and *Meetings* has lots of other materials.hth.

**UPDATE**
I came across a [paper](http://bcmi.sjtu.edu.cn/~blu/papers/2007/5.pdf)

- "Incremental Learning of Support Vector Machines" by Classiffier Combining by Wen and Lu.

stating superior performance and efficiency than concept drift methods.

Comment: whenever possible please provide enough information to still be able to access the information in case the link dies (e.g., instead of "this guy", provide the user name)

Comment: yes, you are right. fixed.